# Wondering if there is a way to make .tabset in Rmarkdown but not with the default of opening up the first tab?

Tags: html, css, r-markdown

I'm curious if anyone knows in Rmarkdown how to not select a tab by default and show it's content? I'm actually getting pretty close, so for example using the code below I'm getting nothing popping up by default because of that "dummy" tab with no content, but I'd like that dummy tab to not appear. Even if I could change tab to completely white I think that would do the trick, or other suggestions are welcome. I think this could be accomplished in a .css file but not sure how to edit ONE tab with a css for a html output.

```
---
title: "Example"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: simplex
    code_folding: hide
    output: bookdown::html_document2
---

##Stuff {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

###{-}

###A

###B {.tabset .tabset-fad .tabset-pills} 

###C {.tabset .tabset-fad .tabset-pills}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a work around method that seemed to work. Made a css file, inspected properties in google chrome, selected for something applicable to only that tab and changed the background color to white and made it non clickable: `{background-color: #ffffff;pointer-events: none;}`